# select * from table on MYSQL linked server returns column cannot be NULL error MYSQL has date field set to default '0000-00-00'

Tags: mysql, sql-server, date, null, linked-server

I'm trying to import tables from a MYSQL database via a linked server. The MYSQL database has all the date fields set to a default of '0000-00-00'. I can't even list the contents via a stored procedure as I get the following error.
An unexpected NULL value was returned for column "[MYSQL_progmgt]...[dbo.project].date_completed" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL_progmgt". This column cannot be NULL.

If I use any other table that doesn't have dates everything works fine.
I also need to import tables (that contain dates) from another MYSQL database via a linked server as well and have no problems as the default date fields are left as NULL values.

My stored procedure is

```
USE [TEST_COPY_PETER]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[RAP_weekly]    Script Date: 2/25/2022 10:57:03 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RAP_weekly] 
AS

Select * from [MYSQL_progmgr]...[dbo.project]
```

I've also tried to retrieve a single field for clarity with
Select NULLIF(date_completed,'1901-01-01') as date from [MYSQL_progmgr]...[dbo.project]

Select COALESCE(date_completed,'1901-01-01') as date from [MYSQL_progmgr]...[dbo.project]

Can't figure it out.

My sql server is version 2019 we are using MYSQL 5.3 ODBC driver.

The table on the MySQL side has the date fields set as
deployment_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'

table on the SQL server side is not created yet as I can't even read the MySQL table.

Pete
**here is the modified working code.note the quadruple single quotes.**

```
DECLARE @OPENQUERY nvarchar(4000), @TSQL nvarchar(4000),  @TSQL_SELECT nvarchar(4000), @LinkedServer nvarchar(4000)
SET @LinkedServer = 'MYSQL_ECHEANCIER'

SET @OPENQUERY = 'Select    nullif( project.deployment_date, ''''0000-00-00'''') as deployment_date  FROM OPENQUERY('+ @LinkedServer + ','''
SET @TSQL = 'SELECT * from dbo.project'')'

EXEC (@OPENQUERY+@TSQL)
```

Comment: change the default value, as it is not valid, the is a year bc and 1 ac

Comment: I can't change the default value as I only have read permission on the MySQL server.

Comment: I just tried  this way as well. SELECT deployment_date from OPENQUERY([MYSQL_progmgt],'select deployment_date from dbo.project') with the same result.

Comment: `SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, date_completed) FROM [MYSQL_progmgr]...`

Comment: apparently 0000-00-00 is ok for a default value in MySQL but SQL server see the field as NOT NULL but also interprets 0000-00-00 as a NULL, which contradicts the NOT NULL.

Comment: It's "ok" meaning MySQL _allows it_ but that doesn't mean it's not utter garbage.

Comment: i don't see how you can make a sql server  use that date. as i said change the default value

Comment: TRY_CONVERT gives the same error.  I also tried COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT .... with same error.

Comment: I was hoping for an option to ignore NULL errors or something along that line,  Since I have no way to change the default dates set to 0000-00-00.

Comment: Is there a reason why there is a -1 on the question? Seems to me everything was valid.

Comment: Don't worry about downvotes. It's a flaw in the Stack Overflow design that anyone can downvote anonymously for any reason, no matter how far their opinion is an outlier.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on -1 . As for my problem , i think I can get the dates I need from another database (SQL)  Not what I had hoped but it will have to do. Thanks everyone for your responses!

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL date handling is broken-by-design. Not only does it allow '0000-00-00' in dates, it also allows '00' to appear in month and day components that have a valid year - and both of the options to turn off such nonsense, `NO_ZERO_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`, are deprecated. My recommendation would be to burn CPU cycles on both sides of the linked server connection - in the MySQL query use `DATE_FORMAT` to convert the date to an ISO-formatted string, on the SQL Server side use `TRY_CONVERT` to get (valid) values back into a date data type.

Answer (score 1):

If a column does not accept NULL value; the appreciate solution is two handle the NULL value all the time. In your case use the minimum value of datatime which is 1753-01-01.

```
ISNULL(date_completed, '1753-01-01')
```

OR

```
ISNULL(date_completed, Cast('1753-01-01' as DateTime))
```

Comment: Got it to work like this. Add the modified code above. Pete